# Unable to install AUTHBIND on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, port, centos6

I tried to install authbind but getting below error,

[image]

Can anyone please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There this project here : https://github.com/tootedom/authbind-centos-rpm

You can easely download this file with :

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aaronsilber/public/authbind-2.1.1-0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

and install it with :

```
rpm -Uvh https://s3.amazonaws.com/aaronsilber/public/authbind-2.1.1-0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: This still fails with `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by authbind-2.1.1-0.1.x86_64` on CentOS 6.7

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer by irrational won't work because that rpm is built against libc2.14 which is only on centos 7 not 6.

```
rpm -Uvh authbind-2.1.1-0.1.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
       libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by authbind-2.1.1-0.1.x86_64
```

I think you have to build the rpm yourself from the instructions at  https://github.com/tootedom/authbind-centos-rpm

I'm having some trouble because the spec file appears to have some errors.
UPDATE:

step-by-step instructions:

```
svn co https://github.com/tootedom/authbind-centos-rpm.git
mkdir /root/rpmbuild
cp -R authbind-centos-rpm.git/trunk/authbind/* /root/rpmbuild/
cd /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/authbind/authbind_2.1.1.tar.gz
mv authbind_2.1.1.tar.gz authbind-2.1.1.tar.gz
cd ../
rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/authbind.spec
```

After all that fix up the rpm actually built and is now at:

```
/root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/authbind-2.1.1-0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

You can now install that using rpm -Uvh and have access to authbind like dem debian peeps.

I did this on centos 6.7 minimal os

Answer (score 1):

I have Centos6, and was having trouble getting a version that would work. Perhaps my solution is just cutting the Gordian knot with a sword, but here goes.

I needed to do use authbind in the first place because I was trying to make Tomcat work on port 80. If that's why your messing with authbind, this should be especially helpful.

I also couldn't make Tomcat work with all the various authbind variations. The one thing that I did do that is worth reporting is that you can just get the gnu sources for authbind and build them and run them. They have supported ipv6 since 2012. If you are having trouble wrestling with distribution managers to make authbind work, including problems with glibc, this approach might be useful. As far as I can tell, authbind doesn't do anything that requires a new glibc, so this worked well, and authbind runs on my Centos 6 happily and without problems.

Keep in mind that this is Linux, sources are available, and sometimes it's easier just to rebuild something than try to get it from a distribution source, especially, as here, when the problem in getting established software like authbind to work with an old version of glibc.

So, First get the tarfile. I got it from:

http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/authbind/authbind_2.1.1.tar.gz

create a directory, then "tar xvf", and then do a "make all" and "make install"

However, the solution that worked for me (as I mentioned, I needed authbind in order to make port numbers less than 1024 available to tomcat), was simply to change the iptables, which I did as follows. (You can cut and paste this into a script if you want to save it for future reference.)

```
# check that rules are not there already
# note: you must be root; if you aren't do a su, or sudo before each line
iptables -L -n -t nat
# Add rules
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
# Check
iptables -L -n -t nat
# Save
service iptables save
iptables -L -n -t nat
```

Giving credit where it's due, this is described well (but with some errors that should be obvious) at 
https://www.locked.de/how-to-run-tomcat-on-port-80/

Marklan